# Edit mysql database from "GET" index.php?id=XX

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I'm currently learning PHP.  I've code a simple bucketlist script with a admin panel, sessions etc just to see if I can do it.

The last page I am coding is the "edit.php" & "editone.php" I have a table which returns all data within the database "ID, Goal & Rating" my fourth column returns "EDIT" as a link which will link off to: `editone.php?id=xx`

editone.php currently is not a page.  For the life of me I cannot figure out how I code the editone so I can grab the data and UPDATE mysql. I'm almost there just cannot piece together the puzzle.

Here's the core of my code for the edit page.

```
<?php
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    { 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$query_row['id']."</td><td>". $query_row['goals']."</td><td><span class='label label-inverse'>". $query_row['rating']."</span></td><td><a href='editone.php?id=".$query_row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>"; 
        echo "<tr>";
    }
?>
```

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you're learning PHP, please stop using `mysql_query` immediately and instead invest the small amount of time required to pick up [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or `mysqli`. These are the modern interfaces to MySQL under PHP and provide significant safety improvements over the old, creaky `mysql_query` interface because they support [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You will acquire many bad habits with `mysql_query` and from tutorials that use it which will be difficult to break.

Comment: Liked your suggestion. Nice explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the warning... I will do some research on this.

Answer (score 2):

Send all the parameters through POST method to editone page. I mean in your edit page, you are getting all the variables from database. You can show them in a form having a submit button and of type "POST". So now when someone submits, it goes to editone.php page.

Get all the variables first through $_POST method. Then write a update query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET goals = '$goal', rating='$rating' WHERE id = $id";
```

make sure to escape your post variables as said in the comment.

This is how should be your PDO Update statement.

```
// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
$goals = 'Some goals';
$rating = 'whatever rating';
$id = 3;
// query
$sql = "UPDATE tablename 
        SET goals=?, rating=?
        WHERE id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($goals,$rating,$id));
```

Comment: **NO**. You cannot do this without first [escaping any user data used in your query](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please do not **EVER** do this sort of thing without being extremely careful.

Comment: I was giving an idea. I didn't even think of writing the query. I agree to what you say. but He is just a beginner. Let him enjoy with outputs for sometime. He will understand its value.

Comment: You know, he probably wants editone.php to first display the data so it can be edited in the first place...

Comment: Yes Rytmis... I do want that... how I got around this was rather than just posting the ID I sent the goal & rating through using the GET and then had the value of the form waiting on the other side as the respective variables... this seems like a harder way of doing it... but at the moment it's the only way I know.... sigh!

Comment: "editone.php currently is not a page. For the life of me I cannot figure out how I code the editone so I can grab the data and UPDATE mysql." - @Rytmis, this is what he wrote.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I read the same sentence -- I'm just trying to be helpful here by interpreting OP's intentions.

Comment: Sorry folks, seemed like I must have not made myself very clear... Rytmis is however correct.

Comment: @Rytmis, no offence, with that i meant my answer to that was with respect to what i read in that line. I was wondering if i have interpreted it wrongly. Dont take me wrong.

Comment: Thanks for updating with PDO. That's a million times better.

Comment: I completely agree with that. Thanks for the strong words. It was worth saying. Cheers

Comment: @AbhishekSaha It's all good. I was being lazy and trying to avoid writing an answer myself. Ended up doing it anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you want is a page that first *displays* a single row (so it can be edited) and *then* saves it once you're done. So you start out by writing the HTML form with no data in it.

Next, you read the ID from the query string:

```
<?php 
    $rowId = $_GET['id'];
```

and then query for the data:

```
// database connection example borrowed from Abhishek
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$sql = "SELECT goals, rating FROM tablename WHERE id = ?";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($rowId));
$row = $query->fetch();
```

Now, you can use the data to populate your form. This gets you about halfway there. :-)

You'll want the actual save to be in response to a `POST` request, not `GET`. There's a [long and somewhat complicated](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) explanation on why that is, but the simplified version is that you use `POST` whenever you're making changes for the user, and `GET` when you're just reading data -- there's a bunch of browser and proxy behavior and whatnot tied to these assumptions, so it's a good idea to start doing things the right way early on.

When you process the `POST` request -- you can do it on the same page -- you'll have the updated form values for grabs, and you can use them to update your database:

```
// This can be a hidden field on the form...
$rowId = $_POST['id'];
$goals = $_POST['goals'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];

// database connection example borrowed from Abhishek
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET goals = ?, rating = ? WHERE id = ?";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($goals, $rating, $rowId));
```

After this, your database should be updated. To finish things off, you'll probably want to [redirect back to the page](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) to make sure the form can't be double-submitted accidentally.

I haven't covered quite *everything* here, a bit on purpose. It's more fun when there are some blanks to fill in. :-)

Answer (score -2):

The most common solution is to use an html form. The input values of this form are a `select` with the `id` in query string. When a submit button is pressed to save this, make a update. But I want share with you [a good and complete web 2.0 example](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html).

Comment: IMO, your web 2.0 example is likely to be overwhelming and confusing to someone who is just trying to come to grips with the basics.

Comment: Thank you for your input... I have booked this as I don't want to overload on information...

Answer (score -2):

You probably want your second `<tr>` to be `</tr>`.

Comment: This is a comment, not a proper answer.

Comment: I can't write comments. Too few points I guess. Thanks master hackers!